# Riemannian Gradient of Riemannian gradient norm

Tags: normed-spaces, riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis, chain-rule

Suppose M is a Riemannian manifold and the function $f: \mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar function and $\mathrm{grad}f(x) \in T_x M$ is a gradient computed at the point $x \in \mathcal{M}$.

Here, I would like to calculate the norm of the gradient again, that is,

$\mathrm{grad}(\|\mathrm{grad}f(x)\|_x)$

If $\mathcal{M} = \mathbb{R}^d$ (Euclidean space), then this gradient is easily computed as $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\|\nabla f(x)\|}} H\nabla f(x)$.

For a general Riemannian manifold, is this the same?

Comment: The exact same computations give the exact same result in a Riemannian manifolds

Comment: Could you let me know the derivations of the above examples?

Comment: On the one hand, $d\|\nabla f\|^2 = 2g(\nabla^2f,\nabla f) = 2 \mathrm{Hess} f (\nabla f,\cdot)$, and on the other hand, $d\|\nabla f\|^2 = 2 \|\nabla f\| \, d\|\nabla f\|$ (almost everywhere).

Comment: Did you try to calculate?

Comment: Yes, maybe I didn't understand the gradient properly. Could you recommend some literature on such computations?